# Transform Rectangle to trapezoid for perspective

Tags: c++, math, opencv, perspective

I have picture from front-view. and I want to turn this into bird's eye view.
Now I want to calculate for each point in the rectangle (x,y) what will be transformed x,y in the trapezoid.
[image]

there must be a formula for this transformation with a given x and y and also the angle of the trapezoid (a).

I am programming in C and using opencv.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Did you consider the [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) transform. You use this to create or correct perspective in an image, I think that it is exactly what you want.

With OpenCV, you can use the method [cv::findHomography()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=homography#findhomography). The arguments are the 4 initial points (vertices of your rectangle) and the 4 final points (the vertices of the trapeze). You get a transformation matrix that you can then use with [cv::warpPerspective()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) or [cv::perspectiveTransform()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform).

Comment: Yes, believe me I have google this in any direction. but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out a way for your problem.

Here is the code I used for the same:

Importing the required packages:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

Reading the image to be used:

```
filename = '1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',img)
```

[image]

Storing the height and width of the image in separate variables:

```
ih, iw, _ = img.shape
```

Creating a black window whose size is bigger than that of the image and storing its height and width in separate variables:

```
black = np.zeros((ih + 300, iw + 300, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('black.jpg',black)
bh, bw, _ = black.shape
```

[image]

Storing the 4 corner points of the image in an array:

```
pts_src = np.array([[0.0, 0.0],[float(iw), 0.0],[float(iw), float(ih)],[0.0,float(ih)]])
```

Storing the 4 corner points of the trapezoid to be obtained:

```
pts_dst = np.array([[bw * 0.25, 0],[bw * 0.75, 0.0],[float(bw), float(bh)],[0.0,float(bh)]])
```

Calculating the homography matrix using `pts_src` and `pts_dst`:

```
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
```

Warping the given rectangular image into the trapezoid:

```
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img, h, (black.shape[1],black.shape[0]))
cv2.imwrite("im_outImage.jpg", im_out)
```

[image]

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you alter the values in the array `pts_dst` you will be able to get different kinds of quadrilaterals.